# System.AggregateException occurred - Collection was modified

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following Entities in Entity Framework Core 1.1:

```
public class Question {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 AuthorId { get; set; }
  public String Content { get; set; }
  public virtual User Author { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
} 

public class Answer {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 QuestionId { get; set; }
  public Int32 AuthorId { get; set; }
  public String Content { get; set; }  
  public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
  public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<Int32> {
  public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
  public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();
}

public class Context : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Int32> {
  public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

  public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) { }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Question>(b =>
      b.ToTable("Questions");
      b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
      b.Property(x => x.Content).HasMaxLength(400).IsRequired(true);
      b.HasOne(x => x.Author).WithMany(x => x.Questions).HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    });

    builder.Entity<Answer>(b =>
      b.ToTable("Answers");
      b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
      b.Property(x => x.Content).HasMaxLength(4000).IsRequired(true);
      b.HasOne(x => x.Author).WithMany(x => x.Answers).HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
      b.HasOne(x => x.Question).WithMany(x => x.Answers).HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);        
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to create a list of questions (in the following code I am adding only one):

```
    List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();

    questions.Add(new Question {
      Approved = DateTime.UtcNow,
      Author = context.Users.First(),
      Content = "question",
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
      IsApproved = true,
      Level = context.Levels.First(),
      Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
      Answers = new List<Answer> {
        new Answer {
          Approved = DateTime.UtcNow,
          Author = context.Users.Last(),
          Content = "answer",
          Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
          IsApproved = true,
          Updated = DateTime.UtcNow  
        }
      }
    });

    context.AddRange(questions);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When adding the questions I get the following error:

```
System.AggregateException occurred   
InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

This was working on EntityFramework 1.0.1. I got the error when migrating to 1.1.

If I comment the code line `Author = context.Users.Last(),` in Answer then it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Usually attaching the whole object as navigation property when saving is not a good idea since it might insert a new record. My guess is that it is trying to add a user when creating the question which may cause the Users list to be in a collection modified state.

The best shot would be to get the first and last user first before creating the object and then do the object creation.

```
var firstUser = context.Users.First();
var lastUser = context.Users.Last();

List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();

questions.Add(new Question {
  Approved = DateTime.UtcNow,
  Author = firstUser,
  Content = "question",
  Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
  IsApproved = true,
  Level = context.Levels.First(),
  Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
  Answers = new List<Answer> {
    new Answer {
      Approved = DateTime.UtcNow,
      Author = lastUser,
      Content = "answer",
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
      IsApproved = true,
      Updated = DateTime.UtcNow  
    }
  }
});

context.AddRange(questions);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```